# Magit + Emacs + Windows: 7 alert dialogs on first use?

Tags: magit

**Background**

The first time I run `magit-status` after starting Emacs, I get a series of 7 alert dialogs popping up. Each one just says "emacsclient 25.1" and has an OK button. They don't seem to do anything at all.

Nothing in the `*Messages*` buffer seems to relate to this.

I saw some reference in the Magit manual about needing to locate emacsclient, so I did put `C:\Emacs\bin` into my path.

This only happens the first time. After that, `magit-status` works fine without any popups at all.

*Edit* More information... It looks like this is coming from within Magit's `with-editor-locate-emacsclient`.

I just tried running that function directly. Got the same bunch of dialogs. After confirming them all (they only have "OK" buttons, so confirm it is, I guess!) I get something in `*Warnings*`:

> Warning (with-editor): Cannot determine a suitable Emacsclient
>
> Determining an Emacsclient executable suitable for the current Emacs
>   instance failed.  For more information please see
>   https://github.com/magit/magit/wiki/Emacsclient. Warning
>   (with-editor): Cannot determine a suitable Emacsclient
>
> Determining an Emacsclient executable suitable for the current Emacs
>   instance failed.  For more information please see
>   https://github.com/magit/magit/wiki/Emacsclient.

It looks a lot like a path problem, even though the directory that has emacsclient.exe is on my path.

**System Config**

- Magit 2.10.2
- Windows 10
- Emacs 25.1.1

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

Magit has a library called `with-editor` that attempts to locate a suitable `emacsclient` on the host machine.

For some reason, the `emacsclient.exe` in Emacs 25.1 for Windows doesn't report its version to the console. Instead it pops up the dialog box I've been seeing.

See https://github.com/magit/with-editor/issues/21 for another report of the same issue.

As suggested by the maintainer of Magit, I set `with-editor-emacsclient-executable` to nil, but only on Windows:

```
(if (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
    (setq with-editor-emacsclient-executable nil))
```

After that, no more popups.

Comment: I would recommend that, instead of using `nil`, you manually determine the path to the `emacsclient` executable and use the path to that as the value. Of course the downside is that the location may change, and then things break again, but you could counter that by checking whether the path is still valid and else falling back to `nil`.